# Подача изображения с текстом в нейронную сеть

Tags: нейронные-сети

Решил попробовать создать нейросеть по распознаванию текста с картинки (текст написан isocpeur курсивом). В целом, как подать картинку (32х32) и получить ответ, что это за буква/цифра я могу. 
Но какой порядок действий До подачи картинки 32х32 в нейросеть (картинка может быть разного размера). Каким образом мне "нарезать" сами буквы для последующей подачи в н.с?

Answer (score 1):

Их в принципе нужно сжимать(ресайзить-resize).Такой код PIL попробуйте:

```
from PIL import Image
size=(128,128)
saved='lena.jpg'
img=None
img=Image.open('lena.jpg')
img.thumbnail(size)
#img.show()
```

Comment: А зачем `img=None`?

Comment: Ну это я по Крису Касперски(рекомендации) - так видно что это не число, а обьект.

Comment: Просто, на следующей строке сразу делается присваивание :)

Comment: Это мой секрет,ну ладно пользуйтесь)

Comment: Нет, спасибо :) В питоне числа тоже объекты, да и на следующей же строке этой переменной присваивается объект (ссылка на него). Поэтому, считаю, что присваивание `None` ненужное действие, больше смысла было использовать типизацию, типа: `img: Image = None`